# Run a cron job now

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a shell script called `import.sh` . This script will be used only once and will run for atleast `2` days.

I am able to schedule a `cronjob` like below.

```
02 10 25 7 * while IFS=',' read a;do /home/$USER/import.sh $a;done < /home/$USER/input/xaa
```

`input.sh` is the shell script

`xaa` is the file that contains arguments.

Now I want to run this script now.

I have tried `./import.sh xaa` and `sh -x import.sh xaa` but If I run them in a terminal then I have to leave the terminal open for the time the script runs which might take more than `2` days.

How can I schedule the job to run now and terminate as soon as it finishes.

Comment: I suggest to use an `at` job (`man at`).

Comment: Much easier to do if using systemd timers, which are available out-of-the-box on many modern distros (CentOS, RHEL, Fedora, current Ubuntu, etc), instead of cron jobs.

Comment: that said, if you just want an equivalent to leaving a terminal open, `screen` or `tmux` will do nicely (and will let you reattach and interact at will).

Comment: `nohup` will make sure that the commands keeps running when the terminal is closed : `nohup ./import.sh xaa`. I do not understand how systemd timers solve this problem easier than the nohup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the command line interface for `Linux`, prefixing any command with `nohup` prevents the command from being aborted if you log out or exit the command line interface.

So you can do something like below.

```
nohup ./import.sh xaa
```